# How to align in a while?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Currently I'm displaying all my MySQL colmns with the following code:

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM XXX");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['Field']);
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fields[]" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" checked /> <?php echo $name; ?> <br />
<?php
}
?>
```

At the moment I have like 50 columns, it'll create a long list from the top to the bottom with checkboxes. However I don't like it that way, I want to have it aligned next to each other. How is it possible to align the results INSIDE a while? I have tought of possible ways but to be honest I couldn't find one.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: You type 'break;' when you want to exit...

Comment: It's as easy as `break`

Comment: Also - with that structure, you're going to get a <form> tag on every row.  Move the <Form> outside the while loop.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I think I've misspelled it. I don't exactly mean break like the php function, it was just something that came up in my mind. What I actually want is the results aligned next to each other.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong questions here. If you only want to return a certain number of results from the database, try using LIMIT in the MySQL query. If you wanted to align the Check boxes a different way, you need to be thinking about the HTML and CSS rather than the PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @circusdei Thanks mate, noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is commenting the simple solution [`break;`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), but I'm assuming you didn't know how to count up to the 50 you want to break at.  Use an [incrementing variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $i < 50) {
    // do stuff

    if(another_reason_to_break) {
        break;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

This will increment `$i` each time, and the `while` loop will only continue when `$row` still contains data **and** when `$i < 50`.  Also, you can just [limit your result set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm47351100188208) to 50 rows from the database:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM XXX LIMIT 50");
```